# Save Zoom recordings to Amazon S3 Using AWS lambda using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to upload zoom video recording to S3 using AWS lambda function. This video is not available in my local computer. I have 'download URL' of zoom recording. I don't want to download it into my local computer and upload it into S3. I am looking for a solution to directly put this video file into S3 using lambda function. If I use buffer or streaming, I will consume lots of memory. Is there a better efficient solution for this?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Perusing the S3 API at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations.html, I don't see any actions to store to an object without literally passing data.  Note that streaming shouldn't consume lots of memory, if done correctly.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546904/how-to-stream-file-to-s3-from-url might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @JeffLearman your provided link is helpful. I just made one change from the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546904/how-to-stream-file-to-s3-from-url is I used node-fetch model. Now I am able to upload the files on s3 from zoom download url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stream file to s3 from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546904/how-to-stream-file-to-s3-from-url)